# Every finite n-dimensional Banach space are equivalent

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I am in need of some clarification here.

[image]

[image: Lemma 5.4]
My doubts are highlighted in yellow in the image above.

I have 2 questions:

What does $\left \| \vec{w_{j}} \right \|$ stands for?
Why is $\left \| \phi\left ( \vec{x} \right ) \right \| \leq \frac{k}{c}\left | \vec{x} \right |$?

Explanation would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $w_j$ is a vector in $W$, and $\|w_j\|$ is the norm of that vector.  For your second question, you would need to tell us what *Lemma 5.4* says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$w_j$ is a vector in $W$, and $\|w_j\|$ is the norm of that vector.  $\max_j\|w_j\|$ is the maximum among the values $\|w_1\|,\|w_2\|,\dots,\|w_n\|$.  That is, it is the maximum among the $\|w_j\|$, where $j$ goes from $1$ to $n$.

For the second: by Lemma 5.4, there exists a $c$ such that
$$
|x| = |x_1 v_1 + \cdots + x_n v_n| \geq c(|x_1| + \cdots + |x_n|)
$$
which is to say that
$$
|x_1| + \cdots + |x_n| \leq \frac 1c |x|
$$

and it is this $c$ which is used in the inequality.

Comment: Why did the superscript on the x become a subscript?

Comment: should there be a sum over x on the right hand side?

Comment: Because convenience.  The $x_j$s are just numbers, whether you're using a superscript or subscript.  In the proof of the lemma, they used superscripts so that they could reserve the subscript for notating a sequence.

Comment: What is a "sum over $x$"?  Do you mean a sum of the $x_j$?

Comment: Or perhaps you're getting confused with the notation of 
$$
x = x_1 v_1 + \cdots + x_n v_n
$$
which is precisely what is in the norm on the left side of the first equation.

Comment: I meant that with regards to my second question with reference to Lemma 5.4. Shouldn't there be a 1/c sum | x |?

Comment: @Mathematicing it should be 
$$
\frac 1c |x_1 v_1 + \cdots +x_n v_n|
$$
but by definition, that's just $\frac 1c |x|$, which is what I wrote.

Comment: It is now clear. Thank you.

Comment: Now that I look at it, I suspect there is a mistake in the notes.
It should be 1/c ($\phi(x)$) less than equal to (k/c) |x|

Comment: Yet this doesn't seem to coincide with the definition for equivalent normed space...

Comment: phi(x) is just the vector x

Comment: No.  $\phi(x) = \sum_j x_j w_j$, and $x = \sum_j x_j v_j$

Comment: This is a notational nightmare

Comment: What exactly then is the sum of |x|? Its just the absolute value right?

Comment: The norm of a scalar x is just the absolute value of x. Now I can't seem to arrive at the required inequality-frustrating for hours

Comment: $\left \| \phi\left ( \vec{x} \right ) \right \|\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left | x^{i} \right |_{abs}\left \| \vec{w_{i}} \right \|\leq k\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left | x^{i} \right |_{abs}$

Lemma 5.4 demands$ \left | \vec{x} \right | \geq c\left ( \left | x^{1} \right |_{abs}+ \cdot \cdot \cdot +\left | x^{n} \right |_{abs} \right )$


then $\frac{1}{c}\geq \left | x^{1} \right |_{abs}+\cdot \cdot \cdot \left | x^{n} \right |_{abs}$

it doesn't tally

Comment: No, $|\cdot|$ when applied to a vector is used as a norm for $V$, as opposed to $\|\cdot\|$ which is a norm over $W$.  Hence "$V,|\cdot|$ is a Banach space" at the beginning of the proof.  $|\cdot|$ is used in two different ways.

Comment: And you keep saying "the sum of $x$" or "the sum over $x$" as if that means something.  Cut that out.

Comment: $x^{i}$ is not a vector. Its a scalar. The norm of any scalar is just the absolute value of that scalar. There is no grounds for disputes. Why are you telling me it is a vector.

Comment: $x^i$ is a scalar.  $x = \sum_j x^j v_j$ is a vector.  Just because we used the same letter, doesn't mean they're the same kind of thiing

Answer (score 2):

First question: $\|w_j\|$ is the norm of $w_j $.

Second question: by Lemma 5.4.

Comment: I have studied Lemma 5.4 (just edited the OP) and it seems as though I am missing something.

Comment: What is there a $max_{j}$? What purpose does this serves?

Comment: The purpose of the max is the inequality that is right below, which serves as one side of the comparison with the norm $\sum|x_j|$.

Comment: Why did the superscript on the x become a subscript?

Comment: It is a typo. $ $

Comment: What I find puzzling is that with regards to the $max_{j}$, the 'left' hand side of the inequality is a sum over the norm of $w_{j}$. How is this less than or equal to the product of k and the sum of the norm (or just absolute value since $x_{i}$ is just a scalar) of $x_{i}$?

Comment: The author is implicitly assuming that $\|w_j\|=1$. It should have been mentioned, but it is not a big deal because one can always normalize a basis.

Answer (score 0):

First, since $\| \cdot \|$ is the norm on $W$, $k$ is defined as the maximum of the $W$-norms of the $W$-basis $\{w_1, ..., w_n\}$. That is, $k = \max\{\|w_j\|: j = 1,  ..., n\}$.

Second, although I'm not sure what Lemma 5.4 is, I suspect you can deduce something to the extent that if $x = x^1v_1 + \cdots + x^n v_n$, then $|x|_V \leq \frac{1}{c} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n |x^i|$, where you should realize that I have added a subscript $V$ where I'm using the $V$ norm as opposed to the absolute value of the coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

For the second question apply Lemma $5.4$ with $\alpha_i=x_i$.